# Issue while opening Chrome: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: selenium

I just have installed Eclipse and tried to open Chrome with the below code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/george.infant.rajesh/Desktop/SWs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //open the google
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }
}
```

but when I run it I am getting the below error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'CDC2-D-504PZZ5', ip: '10.237.61.56', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at Mizuho.Demo.main(Demo.java:13)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'CDC2-D-504PZZ5', ip: '10.237.61.56', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 3 more
```

Though google browser opens up, it just opens in the developer mode and pops up to disable the developer mode extensions. Could someone help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Selenium version, ChromeDriver version & Google Chrome version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0, Cromedriver 2.29 & Google Chrome 58.x you can take help of `ChromeOptions` class to disable the infobar and extension popup & use Chrome browser for Automation purpose as follows:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);       
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.gmail.com");
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks a lot for your help. The chrome driver was not compatible I hope, I downloaded the version you suggested and I was able to run the code. Much appreciated.